# fix version of installed package via apt-get

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, apt

I'm stuck on a strange question:

Should we fix version of installed package?
Could it be possible that some major version became incompatible with my php code?

Exemple: I install theses packages on each build on my docker:

`apt-get install git`
 `apt-get install zip`
 `apt-get install unzip`
 `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

could it be possible one day, that a new major major version happen and is not compatible with my application code executed by php-fpm?

Comment: In every other modern package management system version pinning is considered a best practice FWIW.  APT makes it harder because package servers immediately remove non-current packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you listed packages like `git`, `zip`, etc. How do you intend them to become incompatible with your code?

Second, of course, the day will come that new compiler will warn on your code having deprecation stuff used. But that has nothing with `docker`. Docker is containerization technology, it doesn't care about keeping your code up-to-date.

If you are talking about **upgrading** of existing components after downloading docker image - that would probably worth doing.

In general approach could be following: in your development process you use latest (upgraded) images and tools for your `master` development branch, but as soon as you make releases, you `tag` them, and for them it could be useful to make a **snapshot of all used tools**, including docker images, to be able in future to reproduce them.

For example we use `ubuntu:latest` images for `master` branches and for released versions we use versioned images like `ubuntu:19.04`, also making a backup of an image to be safe in case it will be removed from public registry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what i expected. Last question, does pecl use the php version installed on the machine to get the correct version of the package? Exemple: "pecl install xdebug" ==> should i precise the xdebug version or will it find the compatible version by itself?

Comment: Sorry, mate, I have no experience with `pecl`